# C# Waiting for all Async tasks to complete when calling from a non-async method

Tags: xamarin, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, async-await, task

I have the following code in my constructor for a Xamarin Forms project - I want each step to complete (it is basically loading data from a webservice) before calling the ShowPage() method - will this work or is there a better way to achieve this?

````
public MyTabbedPage()
 {
    ....
     Task.Run(async () => await vm1.LoadData();
     Task.Run(async () => await vm2.LoadData();
     Task.Run(async () => await vm3.LoadData();

     ShowPage();
     ....
 } ```
````

Comment: You could probably benefit from something like: https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.TaskLoaderView or reading Stephen Cleary's blog about async in constructors https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html and his NotifyTask: https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs

Answer (score 0):

Improperly calling an async task in a synchronous function can be problematic as it suppresses the details if an exception is raised in the task. Hence it is essential to implement this common issue correctly.

You can use a `FireAndForget` helper placed inside you Helpers folder under TaskHelpers.cs defined as follows:

```
    public static async void FireAndForgetSafeAsync(this Task task, Action<Exception> handleErrorAction = null)
    {
        try
        {
            await task.ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            handleErrorAction?.Invoke(ex);
        }
    }
```

Then, back in your constructor you can do this:

```
 public MyTabbedPage()
 {
     vm1.LoadData().FireAndForgetSafeAsync(HandleErrorInternal);
     vm2.LoadData().FireAndForgetSafeAsync(HandleErrorInternal);
     vm3.LoadData().FireAndForgetSafeAsync(HandleErrorInternal);
     ShowPage();
 }

 private void HandleErrorInternal(Exception ex)
 {
     DisplayAlertAsync("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK").FireAndForgetSafeAsync(HandleErrorInternal);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Always try to avoid loading data in constructor. Just a good practise.
Put it in OnAppearing method and change it to async.

```
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await vm1.LoadData()
        await vm2.LoadData()
        await vm3.LoadData()
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```